# Orchard CMS: Upgrade from 1.3.9 to 1.10.1

Tags: orchardcms, upgrade

I have an old 1.3.9 version of Orchard I'd like to upgrade to the latest version. I'd be happy to upgrade in steps (i.e. 1.3.9 -> 1.4.2 -> ... -> 1.10.1) but I can't find the install zips for older versions. It appears the earliest on GitHub is 1.8.2. I tried upgrading to that but it didn't work.

So I'm looking for recommendations on how to proceed.

Comment: I just found the 1.4.2 download on Codeplex: http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/87538

Comment: I think the latest Upgrade module can do automatic upgrades from version 1.7 to the latest, so your first priority should be getting there I guess.

Comment: Probably I would have tried clean install of 1.10.1 and then exporting and importing...